# How to fetch an entire field from sqlite and copy it on a textfile

Tags: c#, sqlite, console-application

I am using a console application , in which i want to fetch the entire row(field ) from sqlite and copy it on a text file (Unicode)

From the below code I am connected to the sqlite and selecting the entire row

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = C:\APTRABuilder.sqlite;Version=3;");
        connection.Open();
        string conncommand = "Select language1 from builderScreenResourceBundleTBL";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conncommand, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Now i want to take that data and copy it on a text file, How should I do that?

Comment: You're not being very clear - once you say **row**, then again you say **field** (which really should be **column** in a database context) - so what is it now? Do you want to get a single row with all its columns and write that out to a file? Or do you want to get the values of a single column across all rows ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = C:\APTRABuilder.sqlite;Version=3;");
        connection.Open();
        string conncommand = "Select language1 from builderScreenResourceBundleTBL";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conncommand, connection);
        DataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        while(dr.Read())
           {
             //fetch the Rows here.
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean in the while loop i shuld define the path of the file?

Comment: over here you will get the values from database. dr["ColumnName"].ToString() and write login for creating textfile.